# Migrating a Terminal Server - Multiple Names

Tags: windows-server-2016, remote-desktop, internal-dns, remote-desktop-services

I tried migrating our Terminal Server, which is now successful. The terminal server is joined to a trusted domain and normally, we could access the terminal server from our own domain.

I created an A record on our DNS server to route the Old Server name to this new server's IP and whenever I ping it, it works. If I should try to connect to it, it brings up the login prompt and after logging in, I get this error...

```
The connection cannot be completed because the remote computer that was reached is not the one you
specified. This could be caused by an outdated entry in the DNS cache. 
Try using the IP address of the computer instead of the name.
```

I have tried clearing my DNS cache and also tried registering the DNS all not proving to work. What do you think I can do?

**Note: I only have the Remote Desktop Session Host role installed.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's probably because when you migrated the server a new Computer object was created in Active Directory, and an old Computer object still exists in Active Directory.

The RDP client will check if the server name you are trying to reach matches a SPN, thus the client is able to detect that the DNS name you entered is not related to the correct Computer object in Active Directory.

If you can: delete the old Computer object in AD. Or unregister the SPN from the old Computer object and add it to the new one.

Comment: Thanks. I already deleted the computer from vSphere but it skipped my mind to delete it manually from AD since we have a script that does that.